# QWidget painter

Tags: qt, pyqt, qwidget

I have this code:

```
import sys, random, pprint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 700, 700))

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 400, 200))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.widget)
        self.drawPoints(painter)
        painter.end()

    def drawPoints(self, painter):
        #drawing code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What do i expect: area (400x200) which would be painted by `drawPoints()`. `QWidget` inherits `QPaintDevice`. So this code should work. But console says:

> QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
>
> QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

Could you help me, please.

Comment: The problem caused by initializing painter with null paint device. In other words, painter has nothing to draw on. What is `self.widget`?

Comment: @vahanco self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to replicate [this example](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/drawing/), correct?

The major difference appears to be that you are defining `paintEvent()` for the main window, rather than the widget you are actually trying to paint. It would work if you created a custom subclass of `QWidget`, defined `paintEvent()` there, and then inserted that into a standard `QMainWindow` instance, like this:

```
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 400, 200))
        self.setObjectName("widget")

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        self.drawPoints(painter)
        painter.end()

    def drawPoints(self, painter):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    my_window.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 700, 700))
    my_window.setCentralWidget(MyWidget(my_window))
    my_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At the very least, it isn't printing that error message anymore.